# Can invokeAll be used within a RecursiveTask?

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, fork-join

I have read that the following code:

```
invokeAll(a2, a1);
```

is equivalent to:

```
a2.compute();
a1.join();
```

in a RecursiveAction in a Fork-Join.

However, since RecursiveTask returns a value we may have something like:

```
Integer result1 = t2.compute();
Integer result2 = t1.join();
```

And then we should merge result1  and result2 to produce the final result.

Now, my doubts are:

- Can invokedAll be used for RecursiveTasks?
- If so, how can the result of invokeAll calls be merged to return the
  final result?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`invokeAll`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#invokeAll-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask-java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask-) method can be used for [`RecursiveTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/RecursiveTask.html)s. It takes two [`ForkJoinTask`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html)s as parameters, and because `RecursiveTask` extends `ForkJoinTask`, a `RecursiveTask` can be used as a `ForkJoinTask`.

As for getting the results, `invokeAll` doesn't return anything, so you're not going to get the information that way. What you can do is call the [`join`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ForkJoinTask.html#join--) method on each of your `RecursiveTask`s. Because you know that both tasks have completed when `invokeAll` returns, the `join` method will return very quickly.

```
invokeAll(t1, t2);
Integer result1 = t1.join();
Integer result2 = t2.join();
```

However, at this point, you may as well just do the thing you were doing originally, calling `compute` and `join`. Using `invokeAll` is a bit clumsy when you only have two tasks and you need both of their results.